# Breadth First Traversal for a Tree, Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, breadth-first-search

I figured out Depth First Traversal for a Tree.

```
def _dfs(tree, res):
    if tree:
        res += [tree.key]
        _dfs(tree.left, res)
        _dfs(tree.right, res)
    return res
```

I can't seem to find a solution for Breadth First Search. Will one have to use queues or stacks?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to use a queue to hold nodes which you've checked but have yet to recurse into.

Start with the root node in the queue, then repeat [pop a node and for each of its children, perform whatever action you need (`res += [tree.key]`) and push it on the queue].

Comment: When I store them in a stack, do I store them while traversing Depth first?

Comment: Sorry, queue not stack.  I've fixed/expanded my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can go with deques. This is a classic implementation of the bfs from Magnus Lie Hetland (using a FIFO queue).

```
from collections import deque

def bfs(G, s):
    P, Q = {s: None}, deque([s]) 
    while Q:
        u = Q.popleft() 
        for v in G[u]:
            if v in P: continue 
            P[v] = u 
            Q.append(v)
    return P
```